# Unable to attach to application [iisexpress.exe/webdev.webserver40.exe]

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, visual-studio-2012

As of right now, I'm unable to debug any of my ASP.NET web application projects on a completely fresh machine because of the error message above. I'm trying for hours now and it's driving me completely nuts because I'm getting paid for working, not for debugging strange environment errors. :/

**Installation Procedure / Environment**

1. Installed Windows 8 Professional x64
2. Installed Visual Studio 2012
3. Installed Visual Studio 2012 Update 3
4. Installed IIS through Windows *Programs And Features*

Nothing else has been done - no addins, no further configuration etc. Administratior permissions are available...

**Error message**

```
Unable to attach to application 'webdev.webserver40.exe_00001254_
01ce76431af5c900_dc2119bc-2761-480f-b975-4fab7ad27f390'
(PID: 4692) using '*myhostname*'. 
Operation not supported. Uknown error: 0x80040d10.

Do you want to continue anyway?
```

Same error occurres with Local IIS Web Server (IISExpress too...)

**Solutions**

In other forums / threads, various solutions have been mentioned, but none of them really fixed it.

- Rebooting machine
- Reinstalling VS
- Terminating running web server instances

Has anyone else faced this annoying error?

Comment: Try this, make a page, and add this line on Page_Load `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` and run/open this page to see if you can make it.

Comment: @Aristos Will try. VS is currently uninstalling, I will report back in a few hours. :/